# How to use a cell reference in INDIRECT function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have several cells that calculate totals from a single cell from multiple worksheets, in this case "Y3" from each of the sheets that are in Week, where n is an integer from 1 through 10:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Week"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}&"'!Y3"),"W"))
```

I would like to have a cell in my workbook that contains, A1:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10
```

So that way I can update only one cell when I add a worksheet to be counted.  I've tried a few things and nothing seems to work.

Comment: firstly, is your first formula `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Week"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}&"'!Y3"),"W"))` returning the expected result? secondly, your second formula is identical to your first one so could you please amend your post to include the correct second formula?

Comment: and by the way **INDIRECT** does NOT work with ranges in this way: `INDIRECT("{"&A1&"}")` where `A1` represents `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10`.

Comment: The first one is returning the right results...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your formula : `=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Week"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}&"'!Y3"),"W"))`

This formula only work if you have 10 sheets with named Week1,Week2,Week3….Week10

But if you have less than 10 sheets e.g. Week1,Week2,Week3….Week9, your formula will fail and return `"#REF!"` error

The formula workaround is wrapping with a IFERROR() and become :

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Week"&{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}&"'!Y3"),"W"),0))
```

However, if you wanted the formula acting dynamic and in `A1` enter : `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10`

But `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10` is a text string, you need converted it to an array. Using `FILTERXML()` can do the work of which available since Excel 2013

This is an array formula you need to confirm by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER instead of just ENTER:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Week"&FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")&"'!Y3"),"W"),0))
```

EDIT 1 :

And,

if you haven't Excel 2013, you could use this longer array (CSE) formula instead

```
=SUM(IFERROR(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Week"&TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(","&A1,",",REPT(" ",99)),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",))+1))*99,99))&"'!Y3"),"W"),0))
```

After that,

you can make adjustment to `A1` number without changing formula contents

Comment: that's an interesting use of **FILTERXML** just wondering if there is any other function can do the same ie converting a text string into an array quickly?

Comment: Thanks!  This was ingenious and solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

<del>AFAIK you can't do that with a formula if you place the sheet list in a single cell</del> I stand corrected: see bosco_yip's answer! (although you could with a UDF).

But, if you place your sheet list in a column, you can do this (using OFFSET, the list is dynamic, but must be the only data in that column.  There are alternatives if that doesn't suit you):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Week"&TRANSPOSE(OFFSET(A1,1,0,COUNTA(A:A)-1,1))&"'!Y3"),"W"))
```

[image]

Applying the FILTERXML method, to create a non-array formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'Week"&FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b")&"'!Y3"),"W"))
```